# How do I center a sky sphere on the camera?

Tags: skybox

I'm trying to render a sky using D3D 11. What I have seen in tutorials so far uses cube mapping, which I don't want to use. I want to create a sphere, texture it, and center that sphere on the camera, but I don't know how to do the last part.

How do I center it around the camera?

Comment: Simply drop the translation-component in your mvp-matrix.

Comment: what do you mean by drop it, should I set to 0,0,0,?

Comment: Yes. Usually you just use the rotation of your camera and drop translation (and scaling if you happen to have scaling in your ViewProjection matrix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the sphere's world space position equal to the camera's world space position. Or set the sphere's view space position to the zero vector.